# Continuity under integral sign

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity, improper-integrals

Given $0<r<1.$ Define the function $f: [0,+\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ as
$$f(x) := x\int_0^\infty t^{-r}(t+x)^{-1} dt,\quad x>0 \quad \text{and}\quad f(0) :=0. $$
I want to prove that $f$ is continuous on $[0,+\infty).$

I started as follows: taking $\epsilon >0,$ we can prove the continuity on
$[\epsilon, +\infty)$ using   [this theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuity_under_Integral_Sign) where it suffices to notice that for the third assumption we have
$$t^{-r}(t+x)^{-1} \leq \frac 1\epsilon\chi_{(0,1)}(t)t^{-r} +\chi_{(1,+\infty)}(t)t^{-(r+1)}.$$
This implies the continuity of $x\mapsto \int_0^\infty t^{-r}(t+x)^{-1} dt$
on $[\epsilon, +\infty).$ Since $\epsilon >0$ is arbitrary, we conclude that $x\mapsto \int_0^\infty t^{-r}(t+x)^{-1} dt$ is continuous on $(0,+\infty).$ Hence $f$ is continuous on $(0,+\infty).$

Then it remains to prove that $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) = 0.$
Thank you for any hint.

Comment: Using $t=xu$ for a given $x>0$, you can prove $f(x)=x^{1-r} \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u^r(1+u)}$.

Comment: Super hint. Thank you